# yii2 + babel how realize

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, babeljs

I need to transpile a couple of files and then get them **instead of** original files.
I write about babel, and (as for me), this is a good solution.

---

My variant is
1. to do some set of files in `babel.config.json`
2. transpile them to `someDir`
3. in asset do logic, like

```php
if(YII_ENV == 'dev')
{
    // change sourcePath to `someDir` 
}
```

But I sure that this is not a good solution at all

---

So, can you say/show a better way of this

Comment: Do you want to change any js file for dev? if yes then you need to create you own asset file live BabelAssetBunddle extends AssetBundle then can write js for dev.

Comment: @KshitijVerma no,only change on PROD

Comment: as i know if you wants to change in PROD, you can check 
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) in your code.

Comment: @KshitijVerma, i was asked about the right solution. So, you agree with it, right?

Comment: Yes only way to check prod and dev mode with YII_ENV_TEST